# Is there a place to store luggage at Kings Cross St Pancras?

Tags: london, luggage-storage, eurostar

We will be leaving London around 9.30am to visit Paris for an overnight trip and will have two medium sized suitcases, plus our backpacks.

Is there a place in the Kings Cross area where we can store our suitcases, rather than take them all the way to Paris? We're travelling via Eurostar.

Comment: I'll just add to the answers that: 1. there's sometimes a bit of a queue, so you want to factor that in. 2. Don't forget that you need to get to Eurostar check-in 30 minutes before departure time. All in all, you should probably arrive at St Pancras no later than 1 hour before departure.

Comment: The advice of @jcaron is spot on. There is often a mega queue for the St Pancras left luggage when I walk past it to get to the toilets (for which there is also a queue at least for the ladies). Allow lots of time. Please.

Answer (score 4):

St Pancras station offers luggage storage.

Taken from [Network Rail](https://www.networkrail.co.uk/stations/st-pancras-international/):

> **Left luggage**
>
> You can leave luggage at Excess Baggage Co in The Circle.
>
> Monday to Saturday 6:00 – 22:00
>
> Sunday 7:00 – 22:00
>
> For more information call 020 8090 9923 or visit [Excess Baggage](https://www.left-baggage.co.uk/en/locations).

You could also walk across the street to Kings Cross station and use their [luggage facilities](https://www.networkrail.co.uk/stations/kings-cross/).

Comment: "You could also walk across the street to Kings Cross station and use their luggage facilities." they are operated by the same company, so I would be very surprised if there were any notable differences in price/service.

Answer (score 4):

The excess baggage company is 'very' expensive. And you can expect to pay £20 and up per item for overnight storage.

Another option is a company like stasher.com or bagbnb who broker storage at local hotels and business. They both have a couple of location just outside the station.  I have used stasher once, and paid £4 for 18 hours.  I was a bit nervous tbh. But all was ok and I used a small hotel just opposite kings cross.   I did not leave anything valuable.  Just clothing.

Not endorsing either service as I haven't used them enough to form a valid opinion.

Comment: An alternative depending on the exact circumstances of the OP is simply to ask the hotel they're staying at before the trip to keep the luggage for a couple of days. Most are used to keeping it only for a few hours, so they'd have to check if they accept to keep it overnight.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, however the hotel we are staying at before are quite far from the station and even further from where we are staying at after - it wouldn't be economical for us to go back there.

Answer (score 3):

The [Excess Baggage Company](https://www.left-baggage.co.uk/en) offer left luggage services at all the major London termini and at the airports. Prices start at around £7.50 for one item for a few hours. You can get a quote online and book space ahead.

Disclaimer: this is just one company found on a Google search. There may be 
others.  I'm making no recommendations.